# Output a "tab" in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, tabs, mask

a simple syntax question in PowerShell.

I've a variable $content which provides this:

```
id  name    when    ip  msg user_id
50 Felix   2015-07-22 12:51:04 10.1.100.6  "ein link":www.link.de  89
```

I process it like this:

```
$content -replace '^(.+?)\t"(.+?)"(.+?)$', '$1`t"""$2"$3'
```

I get back this:

```
id  name    when    ip  msg user_id
50 Felix   2015-07-22 12:51:04 10.1.100.6`t"""ein link":www.link.de  89
```

But it should look like this:

```
id  name    when    ip  msg user_id
50 Felix   2015-07-22 12:51:04 10.1.100.6   """ein link":www.link.de  89
```

I tried \t and ``t but nothing gives a real tab back.

Can you help me?

Comment: When I try the following, it does work: ``'50 Felix   2015-07-22 12:51:04 10.1.100.6  "ein link":www.link.de  89' -replace '^(.+?)\t"(.+?)"(.+?)$', '$1`t"""$2"$3'`` I get back the following `50 Felix   2015-07-22 12:51:04 10.1.100.6  "ein link":www.link.de  89`

Comment: Oh. That's right. confusing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you're using literal quotes `'..'` so the backtick won't be treated as an escape character. Instead, use `"..."` and escape the additional `"` characters with the backtick:

```
$content -replace '^(.+?)\t"(.+?)"(.+?)$', "`$1`t`"`"`"`$2`"`$3"
```

However, it may be simpler to just include the tab in your first capture group:

```
$content -replace '^(.+?\t)"(.+?)"(.+?)$', '$1"""$2"$3'
```

Comment: Ah ok. But _$content -replace '^(.+?)\t"(.+?)"(.+?)$', "$1`t`"`"`"$2`"$3";_ gives back: _id      name    when    ip      msg     user_id
        """"_ I don't know why.

Comment: Ah, my bad. You also need to escape the `$` signs otherwise it'll try and lookup variables. Also see the edit, have another suggestion.